# Multi-dimensional arrays and pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Let's say I declare and initialize the following multi-dimensional array in C++:

```
unsigned a[3][4] = {
    {12, 6, 3, 2},
    {9, 13, 7, 0},
    {7, 4, 8, 5}
};
```

After which I execute this code:

```
cout << a << endl; // output: 0x7fff5afc5bc0
cout << a + 1 << endl; // output: 0x7fff5f0afbd0
cout << *a << endl; // output: 0x7fff5afc5bc0
cout << *a + 1 << endl; // output: 0x7fff5f0afbc4
```

I just don't understand what is happening here.

1. `a` is the address of the first element, right? In single-dimensional arrays, `*a` should be the value of the first element, but instead it's the same as `a`?! What does `*a` even mean in this context?
2. Why is `a + 1` different from `*a + 1`?

Comment: There's plenty of such post on SO, please do a little search

Comment: Try dereferencing `*(*a + 1)` and `**(a+1)` and you'll see where each point.

Comment: Remember that the first element of a 2-D array is a 1-D array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two dimensional array is array of array.
You can visualize `a` as

```
a = { a[0], a[1], a[2]}
```

and `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` as

```
a[0] = { a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2], a[0][3]};
a[1] = { a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2], a[1][3]};
a[1] = { a[2][0], a[2][1], a[2][2], a[2][3]};
```

**Analysis of your first question**

> `a` is the address of the first element, right?

Yes `a` is the address of the first  element, and first element of `a` is `a[0]` which is the address of the first element of `a[0][0]`.

> *a should be the value of the first element, but instead it's the same as a?

Yes `*a` should be the value of the first element that refer `a[0]`.  And we see `a[0]`  is the address of `a[0][0]` so as `a` . Thus `*a` have same value as `a` which is the address of `a[0][0]`.

> What does *a even mean in this context?

Previously answered, `*a` is the address of first arrays first element `a[0][0]`, and `*(a+1)` is the address of second arrays first element `a[1][0]`.

**And analysis of your second question**

> Why is `a + 1` different from `*a + 1`?

At this time perhaps you can answer your owns question.

`a` is the address of `a[0]` then
`a+1` is the address of `a[1]` which hold address of `a[1][0]`.
You can print the value by

```
cout<<**(a+1)<<endl; // 9
```

Other way `*a` is the value of `a[0]` which is the address of `a[0][0]`.
So `*a+1` is the address of `a[0][1]`. You can print the value as

```
cout<<*(*a+1)<<endl; // 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try and find some good documentation about pointers, arrays, and array-to-pointer decay. In your case, `unsigned a[3][4]` is a bi-dimensional array of type `unsigned [3][4]`. Whenever you refer to it as `a`, it decays to a pointer to `unsigned[4]`, so the decayed type of `a` is `unsigned (*)[4]`. Therefore dereferencing it gives you an array, so `*a` is the array `[12, 6, 3, 2]` (technically it's the pointer to the first element into the array).

Now, `a+1` means "increment the pointer to `unsigned[4]` by 1", in your case it "jumps" 4 unsigneds in the memory, so now `a+1` points to the "row" indexed by 1 in your example. Dereferencing it `*(a+1)` yields the array itself (`[9,13,7,0]`) (i.e. the pointer to the first element of it), and dereferencing again gives you the first element, i.e. `**(a+1)` equals `9`.

On the other hand, `*a+1` first dereferences `a`, so you get the first row, i.e. `[12,6,3,2]` (again, technically the pointer to the first element of this row). You then increment it by one, so you end up pointing at the element `6`. Dereferencing it again, `*(*a+1)`, yields `6`.

It may be helpful to define `a` equivalently as

```
typedef unsigned T[4]; // or (C++11) using T = unsigned[4];
T a[3]; // Now it's a bit more clear how dereferencing works
```